# Chrome Extension Plugin Ability?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I am building an extension for Chrome which gives the user a basic API. I would like for other developers to have the ability to add functions of their own to my API. For example, some developers offer a new "plugin" (which is only JavaScript code), and I want users to be able to download that plugin into their extension.

The main problem I'm facing is this:

- *How do you load new code into an extension permanently?*

Ideally I would like to add code into the extension's JavaScript, but I have no way to write to the file; I am under the impression that I am restricted by JavaScript - is this true?

While I could perhaps load new code dynamically (by downloading some script), that code  will only hold for the current run, and is not added permanently. Rather, it is gone once the user reloads the extension.

The only solution I can see so far is to create a login system where I save each user's downloaded plugins and give him the mandatory option to load them every time he opens the extension.

This method is very messy and impractical, because I don't want to make a user login every time. In fact, I would very much like to refrain from using any login system whatsoever.

What I desire is something similar to what the GreaseMonkey extension does, which is the ability to let users write scripts and allow other users to be able to download them.

I'm obviously looking to create an extension which is much smaller and simpler than GreaseMonkey, but something like GreaseMonkey is more or less what I am looking for.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

All of the "plugins" will be independent chrome extensions. You can then use [Message Passing](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) to send a message to every installed extension and the ones that are plugins should have code that goes something like:

```
if recieve "some identifying key"
then respond "information about this plugin"
```

Now your main extension knows what plugins are installed and can load their JS files using `chrome-extension://[extensionID]/file.js"`.

That should get you started :)

Comment: I like that idea it is very clever , however it 'bugs' me that the if the user wants 5 new plugins he needs to have 5 new extensions on his Chrome ..I wouldn't like that if I was a user

Comment: You could do something like http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ - upload local files to your extension and save them. But honestly, extensions is just a cleaner way of doing it and the user can easily add/remove/disable them. why reinvent the wheel?